# Using rsync to sync only files that are modified

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to sync two folders

`/developer` and `/shared` ( in ubuntu )

when I modify a file in `/shared` , I would like to be able to copy the file to the `/developer` folder

I tried

```
rsync -r /shared /developer
```

But it seems to copy everything, although I changed only two files there.

How to copy only the changed files.

I also tried

```
rsync -rtu /shared /developer
```

somehow I can't get my head around this.

Please help.

Comment: try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/rsync-to-copy-files-which-has-changed) or [this](https://www.tecmint.com/sync-new-changed-modified-files-rsync-linux/)

Comment: I would like to inform future readers that I had missed adding a slash (/) at the end of the source and destination folders. 
Missing that meant shared folder was getting copied inside developer folder and not the contents of shared folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

`rsync -a /shared/ /developer/`

The first time you run that it will update the access times etc. for every file, but subsequent runs will only copy what's updated.

- `-a` means "archive". It implies `-r`, but also `-t` which is what you're missing.
- The trailing slashes on the directory names *are important*. With no slash it'll copy the source directory *into* the destination directory, like `cp` does. This means it behaves differently when the destination already does or does not exist.

Edit: if you expect it to remove files that no longer exist in `/shared` then add `--delete`, and use it *carefully*.

Comment: It worked and thanks for explaining the answer clearly. Sorry for the late reply. Although I want to mention that rsync for a single changed file seems very slow as compared to copying the file directly. But it does give peace of mind, so its well worth it.

Comment: It still has to scan everything to find that one changed file.

Comment: I'm trying to use such command but it sends some files from source to dest each time, those are not changed , docs in pdf it's alwys sending those.

Comment: @amigo421 that should only happen if the timestamps have been changed. In that case it will compare the contents of the files and only send the bytes that changed (none if the file really is unchanged).

Comment: it sounds reasonable , but I don't understand why absolutely static files can be changed. anyway, this is an issue on my side then. thank you

Comment: To expand, rsync v2 from 2006 on macOS says for --archive  "This is equivalent to -rlptgoD".  the man file may vary based on version of rsync.

Answer (score -1):

Well , this also works

```
rsync -au --delete --update /shared/ /developer/
```

Comment: your answer is confusing: `-u` and `--update` are the same thing, also destination slash has no effect on rsync. You should have used `rsync -a --delete --update /shared/ /developer` to keep things clear