# Upload only changed files instead of all files in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-deployment, lftp

My goal is to upload only changed file instead of uploading all files through ftp from gitlab

```
 image: ubuntu:18.04

 deploy:
     only:
       - master
     script:
       - apt-get update -qy
       - apt-get install -y lftp
       - lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME1,$FTP_PASSWORD1 $FTP_SERVER1; mirror -Rnev / /  --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
```

whenever I commit gitlab deploy script, it matches all files with server and then upload new file. 
But for matching with server takes long time.
so, i Want a script that uploads only changes in the server through ftp from gitlab

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports SSH, you could use rsync and sync only files that are modified, like this:

```
rsync -a source destination
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842443/using-rsync-to-sync-only-files-that-are-modified) you can find more information about it.

Comment: My server doesn't support SSh

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few settings of lftp to speed up the synchronization:

set ftp:sync-mode off

set ftp:use-stat-for-list on

Also enable debug to see where most of the time goes.